# Syntax to send two strings in eventArgs

Tags: c#, event-handling

In the following code I need to know the syntax of passing two strings when the event is raised.

```
 [PublishEvent("Click")]
 public event EventHandler<EventArgs<string>> MyEvent;
```

Thanks,
Saxon.

Comment: are none of the answers valid?

Answer (score 19):

The cleanest way is to create your own class that derives from `EventArgs`:

```
    public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private readonly string _myFirstString;
        private readonly string _mySecondString;

        public MyEventArgs(string myFirstString, string mySecondString)
        {
            _myFirstString = myFirstString;
            _mySecondString = mySecondString;
        }

        public string MyFirstString
        {
            get { return _myFirstString; }
        }

        public string MySecondString
        {
            get { return _mySecondString; }
        }
    }
```

And use it like this:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
```

To raise the event, you can do something like this:

```
    protected virtual void OnMyEvent(string myFirstString, string mySecondString)
    {
        EventHandler<MyEventArgs> handler = MyEvent;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new MyEventArgs(myFirstString, mySecondString));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your class and extend for EventArgs, and pass it

```
public class YourCustomeEvent : EventArgs
{
   public string yourVariable {get; }
}
```

Now you have to provide your custom class like this

```
 public event EventHandler<YourCustomeEvent> MyEvent;
```