# How to check click method when button is created from a class?

Tags: c#, button, timer, click

I am using Tabcontrol  and I created a class for all new Tabpages.
For examle when I open a new Tabpage the class creates controls and places them.

```
bttn1 = new Button();
bttn1.Name = "button1";
bttn1.Text = "Start";
bttn1.Location = new Point(3, 405);
bttn1.Size = new Size(75, 23);
tp.Controls.Add(bttn1);
```

So my question is how can I check if this button is clicked?

Also my other question is the same with a Timer tick event.

Comment: Your question is a little vague and it's hard to tell what you are really asking. I guess you want to know how to attach to `Click` event of the button from the outside of your user control that creates the button. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, since it is not placed from the toolbox it doesn't have that click event attached

Comment: Hmm... Now (from your last sentence) it seems that you want to know how to attach to the `Click` event of the button, from code. Are you?

Comment: Yes, and sorry for my english

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'll try to explain with pictures:

Comment: So I have this tabControl: http://prntscr.com/3sztni , and I have a menustrip for a new tabpage. When I open a new tabpage, it creates a tabpages with the same controls, but i don't have the click events of the buttons. http://prntscr.com/3szts6

Comment: I guessed that you come up with this :) I'll edit the answer to address that.

Comment: I still don't see the edit

Comment: Sorry. Something interrupted me. Here it is. Tell me if you have any other question about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily attach to the button's `Click` event from the code:

```
bttn1.Click += new EventHandler(butt1_Click);
```

And here's the handler:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Visual Studio will help you when you type the `Click +=`. After typing `+=`, hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key twice to get the handler.

---

I hope that you have created a [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) for this or have sub-classed the [`TabPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage.aspx) class to create your controls. You should expose the `Click` event of the button from this newly created class through some new event you create:

```
public class MyTabPage : TabPage
{
    private Button bttn1;

    public event EventHandler Button1Clicked;

    public MyTabPage()
    {
        bttn1 = new Button();
        bttn1.Name = "button1";
        bttn1.Text = "Start";
        bttn1.Location = new Point(3, 405);
        bttn1.Size = new Size(75, 23);
        bttn1.Click += bttn1_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(bttn1);
    }

    void bttn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnButton1Clicked();
    }

    protected virtual void OnButton1Clicked()
    {
        var h = Button1Clicked;
        if (h != null)
            h(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Now when you create an instance of `MyTabPage`, you can attach a handler to the `Button1Clicked` event:

```
MyTabPage page = new MyTabPage();
page.Button1Clicked += page_Button1Clicked;
tabControl.TabPages.Add(page);

...

void page_Button1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Okay I got it but where to put my button click code? I mean the code that is executed at click

Comment: And I'm getting an error: delegate 'this' can't be NULL.

Comment: Where do you get that error? I do not see anywhere relevant.

Comment: page.Button1Clicked += page_Button1Clicked; at this row and i get that at runtime when i want to open a new tabpage

Comment: Tell me the **exact** error message you are getting. I don't understand your error message. There is nothing wrong with that line of code. Did you define the method `page_Button1Clicked` in your class?

Comment: Ok the error is gone, but here's my code: http://pastebin.com/hMkw25JS and still when i open new camera the button does nothing. I really appreciate the help

Comment: I made             public void tabpage_bttn1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OnButton1Clicked();
            }            Tabpage tp = new Tabpage(tabControl1);
            tp.bttn1Clicked += tp.tabpage_bttn1Clicked;

Comment: Sorry, but you are doing it very wrong! Why is your `Tabpage` class inherits from `Form`?! `Form` class represents a top level window. I am creating a sample project for you. Wait some moments.

Comment: Here it is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51708844/SampleTabPageControl.zip

Comment: Thank you very much! Last question: can I add parameter to the click event? like    void tp_Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      this with         void tp_Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e, Tabpage tp)

Comment: Nevermind I got it! Thanks again! Can I somehow upvote you or idk?

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742047/1174942) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12498589/1174942) answer to understand standard pattern of sending custom arguments to events. To show your appreciation, you can mark my answer as the accepted answer :) Read [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/178969) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more information.