# Why to define a reference to the event before call the event invoke?

Tags: c#

I found some example of simple event sending. 
I don't understand the line `EventHandler<string> handler = MyEvent;`

Why they need to define a reference to the event and not just use the `myEvent` to make the invoke?

The code

```
    public event EventHandler<string> MyEvent;  

    protected void SendEvent(string e)
    {
        EventHandler<string> handler = MyEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No need to, maybe only for readability from their point of view.

Comment: don't think so ... i saw this Technique in more then one place. you can see on here .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12498589/465558

Comment: Something to do with thread-safety, I forgot. Should be enough to go on for your next Google.

Comment: How this with thread safe ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why assign a handler to an event before calling it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147397/why-assign-a-handler-to-an-event-before-calling-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/09/understanding-c-raising-events.html).

In multithreaded environment it is possible for client do unsubscribe from event after check for null, but before the actual invocation and MyEvent in that case will be null.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (MyEvent!= null)
{
     // If MyEvent is set to NULL (unsubscribed) in another thread 
     // between these two lines, the program crashes.
     MyEvent(this, e);
}

EventHandler<string> handler = MyEvent;
if (handler != null)
{
    // GC cannot connect MyEvent because there is additional reference to it - handler.
    // handler is local and cannot be set to NULL from another thread.
    // The code is thread safe.
    handler(this, e);
}
```

Comment: but there is a listener to the event => that mean that someone have reference to the MyEvent already ( MyEvent !=  null )  => GC will not collect it

Comment: Consider the following line ececuted in another thread between test for null and invocation: `yourClass.MyEvent -= MyEventHandler;` If this handler is the last event handler for this event, this sets `MyEvent` to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is to due to thread safety. Between the null check and invocation, an event handler can be unsubscribed from on another thread, leaving you with a null value if you don't make that assignment.

Comment: I can't add comments to questions, but I found that it was already asked on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147397/why-assign-a-handler-to-an-event-before-calling-it